# Orchard: one property value does not save in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, sql-server-2012

In Orchard I had a model called `MachineRecord` with some properties and all worked fine, but now I added one property, `DateAdded` and when I add some sample data to the db, all values are being posted, exept that property I added later.

*MachineRecord.cs*

```
  public class MachineRecord
  {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual GroupRecord GroupRecord { get; set; }
    public virtual int MachineNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description4 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description5 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description6 { get; set; }
    public virtual int SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string PriceType { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is where I add some sampledata, as I said, before adding that property it all worked fine.

```
    public void AddItems()
    {
      GroupRecord groupRecord = new GroupRecord()
      {
        Name = "Grondbewerking"
      };
      groupRepository.Create(groupRecord);

      MachineRecord machineRecord = new MachineRecord()
      {
        GroupRecord = groupRecord,
        Title = "Hassia zaaimachine",
        MachineNumber = 100000,
        Description1 = "25 Pijpen",
        Description2 = "Traploos",
        Description3 = "Mech. markeurs",
        Description4 = "Max. 30 pijpen",
        Description5 = "+ na egje",
        Description6 = "Ongecontroleerd",
        SerialNumber = 100001,
        Price = 1600.00m,
        PriceType = "Marge",
        Year = 2005,
        DateAdded = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9)
      };
      machineRepository.Create(machineRecord);
}
```

So I stepped into the code and finally I came to a method where something goes wrong, as we can see [here](http://s14.postimage.org/tc97nc7b5/Date_Added_example.jpg) the value and property is actually in the entity, so that's ok, but when I have a look at the other parameters, like `propertyNames` as you can see [here](http://s17.postimage.org/4sql4yfsf/Date_Added_example_2.jpg) it has all the property names, exept `DateAdded`! So I looked further an saw the SQL Query that's generated at the end, the property is not in there, so the database cell is been filled with `NULL`.

I made sure the datatype of the db column is `datetime`, and I removed mappings.bin so NHibernate would cache all properties again, but with no result.

EDIT:

Forgot to post my migrations.cs.

*Migrations.cs*

```
  public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl
  {
    public int Create()
    {
      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("MachineRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<int>("GroupRecord_Id")
        .Column<int>("MachineNumber", c => c.NotNull())
        .Column<string>("Title", c => c.NotNull().WithLength(40))
        .Column<string>("Description1", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description2", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description3", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description4", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description5", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("Description6", c => c.WithLength(70))
        .Column<string>("SerialNumber", c => c.WithLength(6))
        .Column<string>("PriceType", c => c.NotNull())
        .Column<decimal>("Price", c => c.NotNull())
        .Column<int>("Year", c => c.WithLength(4))
        .Column<DateTime>("DateAdded", c => c.WithType(DbType.DateTime))
      );

      SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("GroupRecord", table => table
        .Column<int>("Id", c => c.PrimaryKey().Identity())
        .Column<string>("Name")
      );

      return 1;
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's working now, but I really don't know what I changed, because I just thought I would move on some designing tasks while I was waiting for some answers, I did just move some divs nothing special and then I checked my db table and I saw the date was in it!

So for sombody who gets here too, I can mention some things I am sure I didn't do...

- I didn't run the migration again
- I didn't change anything to my `AddItems()` method
- I didn't change my `MachineRecord`
- I didn't change my db table

Conclusion: Nothing related to inserting that values was changed, so maybe it was because I rebuild my solution (again) or because I restarted VS...

Sorry, I wish I knew what did it... but it's solved. @Ivan Feric thank you very much for your time!

Comment: The mappings are cached in mappings.bin in the app_data folder. So, if the application pool hasn't recycled, you will need to delete that file to trigger the mappings to change. This has worked for me in the past anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you modify your migration file to append the `DateAdded` column to database? If you didn't, Orchard wouldn't be able to recognize with what it should map your `MachineRecord` property..

---

EDIT:

If you're doing modifications of your class structure, those changes should be in different function inside your migrations, not in the `Create()` method.

In your case, you should remove the `DateAdded` column from your `Create` method and add the following function:

```
public int UpdateFrom1()
{
    SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("MachineRecord",
            table => table.AddColumn<DateTime>("DateAdded"));

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to post it, but yes, I did, as you can see in my updated question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Just to be clear, did you just changed the `Create` function with the added column or was it there before? If you're changing migrations you absolutely always have to change the tables in the new function because Orchard won't pick it up. In this case you should have create a new function inside of the migrations with the name `UpdateFrom1()` and it should alter the existing table by adding the new column and end with `return 2;` to indicate that your migrations are now of version 2. You can even inspect your database table with the name `[ModuleName]_MachineRecord` to see if column is created

Comment: Yes, I know, and what is did was just deleting the existing tables and the rule in `Datamigrations` table and run the migration again. I am very sure that's not the problem, because I did that a 100 times after I started. Why am I doing that? because I am testing things all the time and I wouldn't like to have 30 `UpdateFrom()` methods there. So when I finished developing this module I only have 1 or 2 methods. I am very sure the column is actully there and it is the right datatype, as you can see [here](http://s13.postimage.org/ldbabg85z/dbprintscreen.jpg) thanks for helping me anyway!